Chrome Extension: Cannot change tab icon with my Chrome extension
Below is a simplistic Chrome extension that changes the tab icon for every site that is opened. However, the icon does not seem to change when the page finishes loading.
manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Tab Icon",
  "description": "This extension changes the tab icon for any site.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon-16.png",
    "32": "icons/icon-32.png"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}

background.js:
// Debug log to check if the service worker is running
console.log("Background service worker is running.");

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  // Log when a tab is updated
  console.log("Tab updated:", tabId, changeInfo, tab.url);

  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url) {
    // Set the tab icon to the grayscale version when the page is fully loaded
    chrome.action.setIcon({ path: 'icons/icon-grayscale-16.png', tabId: tabId });
  }
});

What I've Tried:

The background script (background.js) is set up as a service worker.
The service worker listens for the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event and changes the tab icon once the page finishes loading (changeInfo.status === 'complete').
The chrome.action.setIcon API is used to update the tab icon to a grayscale version (icon-grayscale-16.png).
I checked for any errors in the service worker's console (via chrome://extensions/), and the service worker seems to be running without issues.
I confirmed that the icon (icon-grayscale-16.png) exists and is in the correct location.

Problem: When I visit any website (e.g., https://google.com), the tab icon does not change to the grayscale version as expected.
Questions:

Is there something wrong with my manifest.json or background.js setup for this behavior?

Why is the chrome.action.setIcon() method not working for my extension's icon change in Manifest V3?

How can I ensure the icon change works reliably for any page loaded in Chrome?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue.



Can't reproduce the bug in Chromium 130.0.6723.116. The extension works for me.

ManifestV3 is notoriously full of bugs that are hard to reproduce consistently. Try removing the extension, then install it again.

@Thomas Mueller
Are there any settings in Chrome preventing extensions from functioning correctly?

@woxxom Tried that, still there.

If your browser is Opera you also need to allow access to the search engine in chrome://extensions for your extension.

what do you mean for tab icon?  The action icon in toolbar or the page icon beside the page title?

@Hug you Nvidia - "Are there any settings in Chrome preventing extensions from functioning correctly?" - I can't think of any. It looks like we don't have enough information to find the problem. Can you upload the entire extension to Github? What is your operating system and chrome version? Which other extensions do you have installed?

@Robbi The tab/page icon to the left of the page title

@Thomas Mueller The code I pasted is a complete one. Except icons images, but do you really need them?
Google Chrome Version 128.0.6613.84 (Official Build) (64-bit),
CentOS Stream release 8

I'm not sure you can change the page icon even if you inject a content script. Anyway with chrome.action.setIcon you can only change the toolbar icon of your extension.
